# Como plotear dos listas de diferentes tamaños

Tags: python

Hola amigos estoy intentando hacer dos subplots el primero es con la lista de valores_a en el eje y e la lista de fechas en el eje x (aquí quiero hacerlo con barritas), sin embargo con la lista de valores_b es cuatro valores por fecha  en el eje y e la lista de fechas en el eje x, sin embargo, el error está que debo graficar como subplots valores_a y valores_b con la misma dimensión y eso no deseo.
¿Alguna ayuda?. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

valor_a=[0,1,2,6,3]

fechas=['2010-04-01','2010-04-02','2010-04-03',
'2010-04-04','2010-04-05']

valor_b=[-2,-6,-2,-4,4,3,2,-2,-1,-4,-5,-2,-1,2,-3,-4,2,5,4,3]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].bar(fechas, valor_a)
axs[1].plot(fechas, valor_b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: En el segundo `plot` ¿Deseas obtener 4 lineas que muestran los valores en las diferentes fechas?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato una línea en la cual por cada cuatro valores se vea cada fecha

Comment: Ok, pero entonces ¿Qué fecha correspondería a qué dato? porque el código no lo puede adivinar.